# Rails 3 tutorial using Device and own authentication i.e. not twitter etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know of a tutorial that goes over using device and a custom authentication i.e. not an external one like twitter etc.

I am using Rails 3, I wanted something simple like restuful_authentication but it doesn't work with rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Good intro to Devise by Railscasts from Ryan Bates: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
More in episodes 210 and 233.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to Devise.  Their documentation on github is quite good, so I recommend starting there.  Here is an example application for the use-case you're looking for:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example